# Change bar button Item from Play to Pause Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm creating a Pomodoro Timer. And I want change the Play bar button item to Pause when I press on it. I've already created the IBOutlet for this button and IBAction.

```
@IBOutlet weak var playButton: UIBarButtonItem!

@IBAction func startTimer(sender: AnyObject) {

    self.playButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Pause, target: self, action: nil)
}
```

But this doesn't work. Please help.

Comment: [link] (http://i.imgur.com/U6NOrp5.png)

Answer (score 2):

try this,

```
func play() {

    var pauseButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Pause, target: self, action: "pause") //Use a selector
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = pauseButton
    //other stuff
}

func pause() {
    var playButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Play, target: self, action: "play") //Use a selector
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = playButton
    //other stuff
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand where to put this code.

Comment: In swift 4, .Pause is replaced with .pause and so is .play.